# can't write into log file using TraceSource Method in C#

Tags: c#, trace

I am using the following code to log the exception, but it's not writing any logs into the file "*mylistener.log*". What am I missing here?

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics; 

namespace TraceSourceApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TraceSource mySource = new TraceSource("TraceSourceApp");
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            TextWriterTraceListener textListener = 
               new TextWriterTraceListener("myListener.log");

            mySource.Listeners.Add(textListener);
            int i = 10, j = 0, k;
            try
            {
                k = i / j;
            }
            catch
            {
                mySource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 12,
                    "Division by Zero");
            }      
            mySource.Close();               
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the compile-time constant TRACE defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the TraceSource to write data to the file, you need to set the [Switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.switch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-property of the TraceSource to a [SourceSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.sourceswitch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance. Change your code as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TextWriterTraceListener textListener = new TextWriterTraceListener("myListener.log");
    // New code starts here
    var sourceSwitch =  new SourceSwitch("SourceSwitch", "Verbose");
    mySource.Switch = sourceSwitch;
    // New code ends here
    mySource.Listeners.Add(textListener);
    // ...
```

In addition to have the TraceWriter flush its content automatically, set [Trace.AutoFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.autoflush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the beginning of you main method (the sample works without it, but it is always a good idea to make sure that the listeners are flushed in order not to loose log entries):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;
    // ...
```

As an alternative, you can also flush the listener explicitly by calling its [Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method at the end:

```
textListener.Flush();
mySource.Close();
```

In real world code, I'd suggest to add a try-finally or using block to assert that Flush is called and that the source is closed.

Comment: after i write Trace.AutoFlush = true; line, it doesn't store the traceevent output. same results obtain for textListener.Flush()

Comment: @Gomathipriya: yes, you are right, the reason was the missing Switch. I've updated the sample.

Comment: @Gomathipriya: the Switch is responsible for deciding whether a particular event should be written to the source. I can only speculate on why there is not default Switch that writes everything.